# How can I setup scripts to run as period maintenance against my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I need to be able to run maintenance scripts against my SQL server to expire records and generally clean up the database.  Is this best accomplished with some sort of trigger or something within the database itself?  I'd like to run the script daily if possible. How can I do this, exactly.  I have a feeling it is pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to [create a SQL Server job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx).

Comment: I do not have a "SQL Server Agent" node in my Object Explorer tree.

Comment: You probably have the Express version of Management Studio.

Comment: On [this site](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx) should be some free tool for this (SQL Scheduler), but the site seems dead.

Comment: @daemon_x, I do not.

Comment: it came down to an issue of rights.  My DB Admin has the server locked down.  I have to ask for permission to do anything.  I thought it might still show up, but I guess not.